# sphinx-build force fail on "download file not readable"

Tags: makefile, build, python-sphinx

## Background

I have some docs which include some download files. See example:

```
Make sure to download :download:`this file</foo/bar_v1.2.tar>` for more details
```

The `site/downloads/foo/bar.tar` file is created and moved into the directory as part of the build process.

I am using the `sphinx-build -M html . site -W`  to build the docs.

## My issue

When we change the version of the file, the file name changes. Sometimes folks can forget to update this place in the docs and rename the download file correctly.

When I run the `sphinx-build` command, I see the following error:

```
download file not readable: /path/to/site/downloads/foo/bar_v1.2.tar
```

... but the build process continues and `sphinx-build` exits 0.

## My question

I would like sphinx-build to error out when it encounters an unreadable file, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

As noted above, I have tried the `-W` which is supposed to turn warnings into errors, but it does not work.

## Other possibilities

My question stated that I think my problem will be solved by causing `sphinx-build` to fail for `download file not readable` messages, but if anyone else has solved similar issues in another way, I would love to hear about it

Thanks.

Comment: The `-W` flag works for me. Sphinx outputs "Warning, treated as error: ..." and stops (Sphinx 4.1.2).

Comment: I suppose that you use `-M` (uppercase M). See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/6603

Comment: I am using the `-M` option ... but I am not following how this is related? (I am using -M as the first flag too.) As far as the version, `sphinx-build 2.4.4` is what I am using. Hrmm.. I ended up just making a wrapper script for sphinx-build ...

Comment: The order of options and arguments that you used doesn't work. It works if `-W` comes last: `sphinx-build -M html . site -W`. It says so in the linked bug report.

Comment: This maybe a version issue. This is what is run `sphinx-build -M html . site -W `, and while it does write the download issues to `STDERR`, it still returns 0. @mzjn Sorry about that, when I checked it just now, I had written the command incorrectly because I didn't copy/paste.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `-b` instead of `-M`?